# How to use variables in regex to calculate averages

Tags: python

Say I have a CSV file like this:

```
2000,1
2001,2
2000,4
2001,8
```

I want python to be able to find the lines with 2000, check the second column for the value, then average the values for 2000. I want this to be done for 2001 too.

Is there any way I can use regex? I've presented a very oversimplified version here; the real data has thousands of rows.

Comment: Can't tell if there is a formatting error here. Are there line breaks between 2000,1 and 2001,2 in the csv? This might be easily handled with pandas.from_csv and then filter and average. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: yes there are line breaks, sorry

Comment: is there a way I can do this without pandas?

Comment: Is there any restriction in the use of other libraries such as pandas?

Comment: pandas won't work for me, I've installed it, but it keeps saying no module found

Answer (score 2):

I like using a regex based approach here.  We can first try using `re.findall` with the regex pattern `\b2000,(\d+)`:

```
inp = """2000,1
2001,2
2000,4
2001,8"""
nums = re.findall(r'\b2000,(\d+)', inp)
nums = list(map(int, nums))
print(nums)
print("average is: " + str(1.0*sum(nums) / len(nums)))
```

This prints:

```
[1, 4]
average is: 2.5
```

Comment: the values aren't in one big string though, there are line breaks. would this still work?

Comment: @Felix, Yes, [it would still work](https://rextester.com/VZUM50872).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nice approach, +1. You might want to add how to get the average. `sum(nums)/len(nums)` is what OP asked for, if I read that correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there a line breaks in-between tuples, I would suggest using `pandas`.

**If this is not the case please see the answer by @Tim Biegeleisen**

```
import pandas as pd

#create some example date to illustrate the logic
df = pd.DataFrame({"variable":[2000,2001,2000,2001], "value":[1,2,4,8]})

df.groupby("variable")["value"].mean()
```

Output:

```
variable
2000    2.5
2001    5.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

In your case you should ingest the CSV file like:

`df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", sep=",")`

Please see the documentation for `read_csv`, to ensure your data is being read correctly.